# Is there way to write string to file without being enclosed in b' ' in python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I am writing a script to convert HTML to AMP. And  have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import argparse
from amp_tools import TransformHtmlToAmp
import codecs

arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description = "Copy source_file as target_file." )
arg_parser.add_argument( "source_file" )
arg_parser.add_argument( "target_file" )
arguments = arg_parser.parse_args()

source = arguments.source_file
target = arguments.target_file
html = ""
with codecs.open(source, encoding='utf-8', mode='r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        html = html + line.rstrip()
        
valid_amp = str(TransformHtmlToAmp(html)())

with codecs.open(target, encoding='utf-8', mode='w+') as f:
    f.write(valid_amp.rstrip())
    f.seek(0)

#print(str(valid_amp))
print( target, "successfully created !!" )
```

Now, this works but the file is saved is enclosed in `b''`. I don't want that. Is there way to avoide quotes in the output file?

Sample input: `<!doctype html> <html lang="en"> <head> <title>News Article</title> <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet" /> <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script> </head> <body> <header> News Site </header> <article> <h1>Article Name</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam egestas tortor sapien, non tristique ligula accumsan eu.</p> </article> <img src="https://www.travelmanagers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/AdobeStock_254529936_Railroad-to-Denali-National-Park-Alaska_750x500.jpg"> </body> </html>`

Output: `b'<div lang="en" class="amp-text"> <head> <title>News Article</title> <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script type="text/javascript" src="base.js"></script> </head> <body> <header> News Site </header> <article> <h1>Article Name</h1> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam egestas tortor sapien, non tristique ligula accumsan eu.</p> </article> <amp-img src="https://www.travelmanagers.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/AdobeStock_254529936_Railroad-to-Denali-National-Park-Alaska_750x500.jpg" width="750" height="500" layout="responsive"></amp-img> </body></div>'`

Comment: Use the `.decode()` method, not `str()` to convert a byte string to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should substitute the row:

```
valid_amp = str(TransformHtmlToAmp(html)())
```

with:

```
valid_amp = bytes(TransformHtmlToAmp(html)()).decode("utf-8")
```